# get_header() Function not working in wordpress plugin folder

Tags: php, wordpress, search, plugins, widget

I searched on why my `get_header()` function is not working in my plugin. All possible solutions say that the `index.php` file might be corrupt. But in my case it's working fine. My error is different from other errors solved on stackexchange concerning `get_header()`.

Please also help me on how to show my `searchresult.php` from plugin folder. If I add any wordpress function in it, it says `undefined function`. like `get_header()`, plugin folder etc.

My code:

```
<?php
get_header();

// Start the loop.
global $wpdb;
$srh = $_POST['s'];
//get_search_query();

if(!empty($srh)) {

    echo $srh;
    // Search title from table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_article WHERE title LIKE '$srh'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(count($result) > 0) {
        foreach($result as $results) {
            echo $results->title;
            echo $results->desc;
        }
    } else {

        echo "no ";
    }

} // submit end

?>
```

searchform.php

```
<style>
.search{
    border:0px solid #E5E5E5;
width: 100%;
height:90px;
padding:0px;    


}
.search ul li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline-block !important;
    position:relative;
    float:none !important;
    text-align:left;

}
.widget input.search-field[type="search"] {
width:100%; 
}

</style>


<div class="search"><?php

/**
 * Template for displaying search forms in Twenty Sixteen
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
$url = plugins_url();  
get_header();
?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo $url; ?>/magicsearch/searchm.php" >
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span></button>
</form>
</div>
```

**My Plugin Dashboard file **
 plugin_index.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Magic Search
Plugin URI: #
Description: Magic Search use for to find article from archive otherwise query saved.
Author: Manmohan
Author URI: #
*/
// PLUGIN ACTIVATION BY CODE
//function myplugin_activate() {
    // Activation code here...
//}
//register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
function createTable(){

    global $wpdb;
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix ."newkeyword (
        query_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        keyword VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (query_id)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    $wpdb->query($query);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'createTable');

//ADD SHORTCODE 
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'searchbar_function');
add_shortcode('searchbar', 'searchbar_function');

function searchbar_function(){

    include('searchf.php'); 
    include('searchm.php'); 

}
// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'disp_queries');
// action function for above hook
function disp_queries(){
    /*               Browser Top   Title use at                                                                                */
    /*               Title Text    WP Admin LFT Bar                                                                               */
    /*                  \/              \/                                                                            */

    add_menu_page( 'Magic Search', 'Magic Search', 'manage_options', 'searchpage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'magicsearch/se.png' ), 6 ); 
}

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    include('adminresult.php'); 


//tguy_sm_summary_table(30);
    }







?>
```

Comment: That's All codes of my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

have you set up the header and footer .php files in the theme folder?
may seem like a silly question, but its been known to happen.

regarding the search question, im not 100% sure on that one, but this [get_search_form topic](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) may help

Is this a custom theme or one you have picked as default?

Comment: its default theme of wordpress . header and footer set in .php file. Every thing working fine except if i add get_header() and footer() function searchresult.php file of my plugin folder.